# Are there sources in hinduistic philosophy regarding the concept of the specifically human?

Tags: reference-request, eastern-philosophy

What I am looking for are sources (wether historical or, even better, contemporary), that stand in the tradition of hinduistic philosophy and focus on the concept of humanity.

The goal is basically developing a holistic, more general understanding of man as destinct from animal in order to become more independent from what could be called 'western philosophy'.

There is a similar question regarding daoistic philosophy [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/38024/are-there-sources-in-daoistic-philosophy-regarding-the-concept-of-the-specifical).

Comment: need to understand better what you are looking for as in all Hindu philosophy man is an evolved animal, animals will evolve into man. That is, from a spiritual standpoint, the souls (or jivas) of animals will one day inhabit men's bodies. From a purely material standpoint, man evolved from animals. Evolution is mentioned in early scriptures. Give some more guidance.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda: Thank you for the comment. What I am particularly interested in would be examples of both a) texts about the material and spiritual continuity between animal and man and b) texts that focus on the discontinuities/specifical differences in between them. The latter would even be of more interest, as they tend to include the other points by pointing out the differences. Referring to your comment, this would include arguments justifying the spiritual order of man as the final (not purely spiritual, I guess?) stage of evolution.

Comment: Probably the Chandogya and Brihadaranyaka Upanishads, Brahma Sutras, and Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms. I'll get some specific verses.

Comment: take a look at my answers to these two questions first and see if you need more ... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14655/atma-and-cells-in-the-body and http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body